# Django + Mac osx how to use less css?

Tags: css, django, less

There is no less css command line compiler in mac osx. But I am trying out a project which needs to use less css.
Also less is used to compress the css files in the project. How do I handle this? I read in less website that its js can be run on a node.js server - http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage
But I am not understanding how to integrate it with django. What should be the value for the COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS ?

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (                                                       
('text/less',""),
```

)

Any help appreciated from someone who has already solved this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Install node.js and npm (I used homebrew to install node.js and the instructions at http://npmjs.org/ to install npm)
2. Install the command-line less compiler with `npm install --global less`
3. [Add lessc to COMPASS_PRECOMPILERS (directions).](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#compress-precompilers)

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Also, COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS is from django_compressor, a django app, not from django itself. I think django_compressor looks quite good, but there are other options available as well.

Comment: I did install less via npm. But could not figure out that there was a command line tool. Well I have zero knowledge on how nodejs works. I was thinking I need to write some server code.

Comment: The command-line tool is documented at the very bottom of the usage section. http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage It would sure be more convenient if it was at the top of the Server-Side usage section! Also I have to run `lessc --help` to get the command-line usage that the django-compress snippet uses, that is, without the `>` symbol. It says `usage: lessc source [destination]`.

Comment: By the way, thanks for introducing me to django_compressor. It looks awesome. I'm going to start using and recommending it, I think.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the --global: without it, the lessc binary didn't get created on OSXX.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the less.app for OS X?

http://incident57.com/less/

Comment: This is the easiest, and nicest way to do it - unless you need it compiled on the fly.

Comment: My project is compiling it on fly. The compressor part. So Less.app is not useful in my scenario.