# Compiling Less CSS files with JavascriptCore jsc binary on OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, app-store, less

The reason I'd like to do this is so that there is no NodeJS dependency and therefore an app can be submitted to the Apple app store that compiles Less files. Any thoughts welcomed.

Comment: Technically you can use "browser script" for this - i.e. `less.js` script instead of `lessc` (Actually some GUI editors do use the `less.js` as their Less compiler).

Comment: But that requires window, document etc. objects to be defined.

Comment: Not necessary. `less.js` provides same `render`/`parse` functions that you can use to compile Less code w/o any window, document etc. See [for example](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/yobdJ?editors=101) (exact code may differ depending on used version though).

Comment: When I create a tester.js file containing "load('less.js');", and run with jsc I get: Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window

Comment: Well, you *will* need some modifications there of course (for instance within your script you can just define some fake `window` object with required methods doing nothing, in particular disabling it from trying to read `<link>` elements on load). Alternatively you could try to write your own [environment adapter](https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/master/lib) for `jsc` but that's apparently much more work.

Comment: Less seems to make all kinds of assumptions which makes it near impossible to achieve as far as I can see.

Comment: Wondering if I might be better creating a WebView and running it via that.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928914/django-mac-osx-how-to-use-less-css/43690788#43690788